# jquery read text from html, multiple classes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have five different name div's, everyone has a different id. 
The first div once, the second divs is 1-5 times and the other three div's, they will never know how many but certainly more than 10 times in whole body.

and I need to read them all through the jQuery (loop) way that I could save every so-called line by line
that jQuery would repeat this process until all have been read and saved. and every time those 5 div's

the third-, fourth-, fifth div, they will always be same amount,

with that code i get only one div info.

```
var kuupaev = "";
$('.page .sub').each(function(){
    kuupaev = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
                url: 'save.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {kuupaev:kuupaev},
                success: function (data) {
                  callback(data);
                }
            });    
 });
```

maybe someone can help me. a big thank you

sorry for bad english...

EDIT: i figured it out..

```
 <script>
 for(var index = 0; index < $(".page_channel").nextUntil(".page_channel").andSelf().length; index++)
 {
    /*
    var pikkus = $(".page_channel").nextUntil(".page_channel").andSelf().length;
    alert(pikkus)
     */

    var kanal = $('.page_channel .1').first().text();  
    var kuupaev = $('.page_channel .2').first().text();
    var kell = $('.page_channel .3').eq(index).text(); 
    var sisu_pilt = $('.page_channel .4').eq(index).val(); 
    var pealkiri = $('.page_channel .5').eq(index).text();  



        $.ajax({
                url: 'save.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {kuupaev:kuupaev,kanal:kanal,kell:kell,pealkiri:pealkiri,sisu_pilt:sisu_pilt},
                success: function (data) {
                  callback(data);   
                }
            }); 
      }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass multiple parameters to the data parameters, like the following example:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'save.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
     div1: 'info from div1',
     div2: 'info from div2',
     div3: 'info from div3',
     div4: 'info from div4',
     div5: 'info from div5'
   },
   datatype: 'JSON'
   success: function(data) {
     callback(data);
   }
 });
```

Then you can get the div info using jQuery as follows:

```
var div1 = $("#div1").text();
var div2 = $("#div2").text();
var div3 = $("#div3").text();
var div4 = $("#div4").text();
var div5 = $("#div5").text();
```

To tie it all together, you will have to pass the variables to the data array

```
data: {
         div1: div1,
         div2: div2,
         div3: div3,
         div4: div4,
         div5: div5,
       },
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion you could write a `for` loop to remove some of the repetition and streamline the creating of the object. Example: `var data = {}; for(var a = 1; a <= 5; a++) { data['div' + a] = $('#div' + a).text(); }`...

Comment: I'm sorry, I explained badly.
I have five different name div's, everyone has a different id. The first div once, the second divs is 1-5 times and the other three div's, they will never know how many but certainly more than 10 times in whole body. and I need to read them all through the jQuery (loop) way that I could save every so-called line by line that jQuery would repeat this process until all have been read and saved. and every time those 5 div's the third-, fourth-, fifth div, they will always be same amount,

Comment: @War10ck Yeah, as long as you know that the ID's are incremental that would be a great improvements. Thanks!